# time complexity of this algorithm written below

Tags: c++, function, class, time-complexity, space-complexity

According to my calculations , the time complexity of this algorithm/code is O(logN) as it is an enhancement of binary search, but while submitting the code in leetcode and other platforms , it is said that the time limit is exceeded . they are also expecting the time complexity of this algorithm to be O(logN), so please confirm is the complexity of code written below is O(logN) or is it different from that?

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int findLast(vector<int> arr, int n, int x)
    {
        int l = 0;
        int h = n - 1;
        int mid;
        while (h >= l) {
            mid = (l + h) / 2;
            if (arr[mid] == x) {
                if (arr[mid + 1] != x) {
                    return mid;
                }
                else {
                    l = mid + 1;
                }
            }
            else if (arr[mid] > x) {
                h = mid;
            }
            else if (arr[mid] < x) {
                l = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int findFirst(vector<int> arr, int n, int x)
    {
        int l = 0;
        int h = n - 1;
        int mid;
        while (h >= l) {
            mid = (l + h) / 2;
            if (arr[mid] == x) {
                if (arr[mid - 1] != x) {
                    return mid;
                }
                else {
                    h = mid;
                }
            }
            else if (arr[mid] > x) {
                h = mid;
            }
            else if (arr[mid] < x) {
                l = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    vector<int> searchRange(vector<int>& nums, int target)
    {
        int last = findLast(nums, nums.size(), target);
        int first = findFirst(nums, nums.size(), target);
        vector<int> v1 = { first, last };
        return v1;
    }
};
```

Comment: The time _complexity_ is not the same as the runtime. You could write something that scales linearly with the number of elements, but takes a year for each one.

Comment: That is, the algorithm looks proportional to `log N` if it actually works, but you're making two unnecessary copies and doing a lot of redundant searching (`first` should precede `last`, but you do a binary search of the whole vector again, even the bit you already know it can't be in)

Comment: You're taking the vectors by value, which has linear time (and space) complexity.

Comment: And you have undefined behaviour in the single-element case due to accesses outside the vector.

Comment: This looks like leetcode problem. Please provide link to problem description so it is easier to read and fix your code.

Comment: [problem description](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-first-and-last-position-of-element-in-sorted-array/) use  [lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) to avoid stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code's time complexity is O(∞) because it can perform an infinite loop.

Consider what happens when you run `findLast` on a one-element vector. You will have `h`, `l`, and `mid` equal to 0. If you enter the `arr[mid] > x` branch then you run `h = mid;` which leaves the variables unchanged, and repeats indefinitely.

Besides this, you should take the `vector` parameter by reference to avoid a copy which would make this a linear runtime.

Comment: it is still not being accepted , I applied all the fixes that you suggested, again it is said time exceeded, after applyng  the fixes ,do you think the complexity still be of O(logN)

Comment: @BhanuArora After these fixes it will be O(logN). Maybe you didn't fix all the cases that cause an infinite loop. You also have the issue pointed out in the comments of reading past the end of the vector with `arr[mid + 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not handle some corner cases where the input could be `[1,1]` and the target is `1`. In `findLast` , the `low` and `high` variables would come to `1` and segmentation fault would occur when you check for `arr[mid+1]`. The same explanation would go for `findFirst` as well.
Try this and see if it helps:

```
int findLast(vector<int> arr, int n, int x)
{
    int l = 0;
    int h = n - 1;
    int mid;
    while (h > l)
    {
        mid = (l + h) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == x)
        {
            if (arr[mid + 1] != x)
            {
                return mid;
            }
            else
            {
                l = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (arr[mid] > x)
        {
            h = mid;
        }
        else if (arr[mid] < x)
        {
            l = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return arr[l] == x ? l : -1;
}
```